# Check if any part of an object value is included in string

Tags: javascript, string, object, functional-programming

I have a string that looks like this:
`/link-to-page?foo=bar&test=1`

Plus I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  key: '/',
  foo: 'bar',
  test: false,
  mock: 'data'
}
```

The thing I'd like to achieve is rather simple (I thought), but maybe I'm missing the obvious here:

I want to check whether *any* value of my object is included inside of my string.

My first thought was doing this:
`Object.keys(obj).map(o => str.includes(obj[o]))` - but this only returns me an array of booleans obviously.

Trying this: `Object.keys(obj).map(o => obj[o]).some(s => str.includes(s))` will not work either since it might provide false positives (in my object I have the `key` with a value of `/` which should not be taken into consideration, but it would return `true` here - I only want to search for "actual text" if that makes sense).

Should I transform the object keys and the string first to get rid of any `/` or is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid any / with replace method

```js
let oldstr = '/link-to-page?foo=bar&test=1';
let str = oldstr.replace('/', '');
console.log(str)

let obj = {
  key: '/',
  foo: 'asd',
  test: false,
  mock: 'data'
}

let a = Object.values(obj).some(s => str.includes(s))
console.log(a);
```

Comment: speaking of "missing the obvious"... thanks! totally forgot about the `.replace()` method. duh!

Comment: let str = oldstr.replace(/\W/g, ''); you can use this regexp to match all non-word characters

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to avoid matching characters

```js
str="/link-to-page?foo=bar&test=1"

ob={
  key: '/',
  foo: '/',
  test: false,
  mock: '/'
}
path=/[a-zA-Z]/
res=Object.values(ob).some(o=>path.test(o)?str.includes(o):false)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store useful properties and then loop through them to check inside your object and prevent filtering:

```js
const data = '/link-to-page?foo=bar&test=1';

const relevantProperties = ['foo', 'test', 'mock'];
const obj = {
  key: '/',
  foo: 'bar',
  test: false,
  mock: 'data'
};

for (let i = 0; i < relevantProperties.length; ++i) {
  const property = relevantProperties[i];
  
  if (data.includes(obj[property])) {
    console.log(property);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your object values and use `.match` method to check whether the values are included in the given string. If the length of the filtered array is `>0` that means matches are found

```js
let obj = {
  key: '/',
  foo: 'bar',
  test: false,
  mock: 'data'
}

let str = '/link-to-page?foo=bar&test=1'

let matchedValues = Object.values(obj).filter(x=>str.match(x)) // will return an array of all matching values
// -> (2) ["/", "bar"]

if(matchedValues.length > 0){
  console.log("Matches found")
}else{
  console.log("Matches found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner

```
let isinclude=(str,obj)=>(str=str.replace('/',''),Object.keys(obj).reduce((a,v)=>a || str.includes(v),false))
```